# How to callback a function on onClick event in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I have `handleClick` event which by clicking `renderDetail` function must be run in `{this.state.ShowInfo[i]}` div.I do it like below code:
I used callback but did not work.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    data: [],
    ShowInfo: {},

  }
}
render() {
  const { data } = this.state
  const renderInfo = data.map((item, i) => {
    return (
      <div class="item">
        <div onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, item, i)}>
          <span>Click</span>
        </div>
        <div>{this.state.ShowInfo[i]}</div>
      </div>
    )
  })
  return <div>{renderInfo}</div>
}
handleClick = (e, element, i) => {
  fetch('/json.bc', {///I can see that the json.bc is loaded in network tab by result/////
    method: 'POST',
  })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
      let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        ShowInfo: {
          ...prevState.ShowInfo, [i]: (Maindata, i) => {
            console.log(Maindata)// console.log(Maindata) did not show anything.There is no result in this part////
            let element = Maindata
            let lenfamilies = element.families.length
            console.log(lenfamilies)//// console.log(lenfamilies) did not show anything.There is no result in this part////
            let indents = [];
            for (let j = 0; j < lenfamilies; j++) {
              let numF = i
              let numS = j
              let stingF = numF.toString()
              let stingS = numS.toString()
              index = stingF + stingS
              indents.push(
                <div>
                  <span
                    key={index}>
                  </span>
                </div>
              )
            }
            return (
              indents
            )
          }
        },
      }))
    }).catch(error => console.error(error))
  }
 }
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("Result"))
```

`<div>{this.state.ShowInfo[i]}</div>` is empty by using callback.Have you any other way to call `renderDetail` function in `handleClick` event?

**Edit:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  data: [],
  ShowInfo: {},
  text: {}

 }
}
render() {
const { data } = this.state
const renderInfo = data.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <div class="item">
      <div onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, item, i)}>
        <span>Click</span>
      </div>
      <div>{this.state.ShowInfo[i]}</div>
</div>
  )
})
return <div>{renderInfo}</div>
}

handleClick = (e, element, i) => {
  fetch('/json.bc', {
  method: 'POST',
  },)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(text => {
 let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'))
 this.setState(prevState => ({
 ShowInfo: { ...prevState.ShowInfo,[i]: this.renderDetail(Maindata, i)},
}))
}).catch(error => console.error(error))
}

renderDetail(element, i) {
 let lenfamilies = element.families.length
 let indents = []
let index = 0
for (let j = 0; j < lenfamilies; j++) {
  let numF = i
  let numS = j
  let stingF = numF.toString()
  let stingS = numS.toString()
  index = stingF + stingS
  indents.push(
  <div>
    <span
        key={index}
        onClick={e => this.handleText(e, element.families[j], index)}
      >
        Click
      </span>
      <span key={index}>
        {this.state.text[index]}
      </span>
</div>
  )
}
 return(
       indents
       )
  }
  handleText = (e, element, index) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
        text: { ...prevState.text, [index]: "test" }////In this part   'test' should be set in  span but it is not been set
  }))
 }
 }
```

Comment: Check this line ```[i]: (Maindata, i) => {``` . it should be ```[i]: { ```

Comment: Hi @Leu.Thanks for your comment. You mean I should remove ` (Maindata, i) =>` of my code?

Comment: If I remove it will have Syntax Error

Comment: yes, sure. object `{}` cannot have `return`. why don't you manipulate data before setting state `this.setState(prevState => ({` ?

Comment: I am sorry, but I did not get what you mean. Can you show me in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `{this.state.ShowInfo[i]}` is a function and to execute its body you need to call it by using `()` with function name.

Also dont forget to add a check before calling it because initial value of `this.state.ShowInfo[i]` will be undefined and it will throw error with `()`.

Write it like this [notice `()` with `ShowInfo[i]`]:

```
const renderInfo = data.map((item, i) => {
  return (
    <div class="item">
      <div onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, item, i)}>
        <span>Click</span>
      </div>
      {this.state.ShowInfo[i] && <div>{this.state.ShowInfo[i]()}</div>} 
    </div>
  )
})
```

**Suggestion:** Instead of storing the function in state variable, better to store data only and write a generic method that will return the jsx part for each key.

Check this snippet:

```js
function print() {
  console.log('body of print method');
}

// it will print the function body
console.log(print);

// it will execute the function body
console.log(print());
```

**Full Code:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      showInfoData: {},
      text: {},
    }
  }

  handleClick = (e, element, i) => {
    fetch('/json.bc', {
      method: 'POST',
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
      let Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'));
      this.setState(prevState => ({
        showInfoData: {
          ...prevState.showInfoData,
          [i]: Maindata,
        }
      }))
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error))
  }

  showInfo(i) {
    let element = this.state.showInfoData[i];
    if(!element) return null;

    let lenfamilies = element.families.length
    let indents = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < lenfamilies; j++) {
      let numF = i
      let numS = j
      let stingF = numF.toString()
      let stingS = numS.toString()
      index = stingF + stingS
      indents.push(
        <div>
          <span
            key={index}
            onClick={e => this.handleText(e, element.families[j], index)}
          >
            Click
          </span>
          <span key={index}>
            {this.state.text[index]}
          </span>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return (indents);
  }

  handleText = (e, text, i) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      text: { ...prevState.text, [i]: text}
    }))
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state
    const renderInfo = data.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <div class="item">
          <div onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, item, i)}>
            <span>Click</span>
          </div>
          <div>{this.showInfo(i)}</div>
        </div>
      )
    })
    return <div>{renderInfo}</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: HI @Mayank Shukla. Thanks for your answer. I Changed `<div>{this.state.ShowInfo[i]}</div>` to `{this.state.ShowInfo[i] && <div>{this.state.ShowInfo[i]()}</div>} ` but the result of  `console.log(Maindata)` is `undefined`

Comment: I tried to call `renderDetail`  function out side `handleClick = (e, element, i) => {})` event.Every thing is done correct except `onClick={e => this.handleText(e, element.families[j], index)}`.By clicking onClick={e => this.handleText(e, element.families[j], index)} the text of <span key={index}>{this.state.text[index]}</span> should be test and test is going to be dynamic. I put test just as testing, but it is not been set. Could you please look at my edited code.

Comment: onClick of Click button you want to update the text or by default you want to show `element.families[j]` value in span?

Comment: When I click `<div onClick={e => this.handleClick(e, item, i)}><span>Click</span>     </div>`, `renderDetail(element, i) {}` will be run.By now every thing is fine. But when click  `<span key={index}  onClick={e => this.handleText(e, element.families[j], index)} > Click </span>` I want the text of  `<span key={index}>this.state.text[index]}
</span>`  be for example `test`,although the text of `<span key={index}>this.state.text[index]}</span>` is going to be dynamic. But For testing I put `test` but it is not been set.I hope you will get What I mean.

Comment: @bita added a full code section in answer, please try that code once, let me know if this is not working as you expected.

Comment: @ Mayank Shukla there is this error:`TypeError: "_this2.state.showInfo is not a function"`

Comment: oh sorry remove `state` and use `this.showInfo(i)`.

Comment: @ Mayank Shukla there is no result in `<div>{this.showInfo(i)}</div>` .When I write `let element = this.state.showInfoData[i];console.log(element)` it is `undefined`